# C, Why the function doesn't accept the 2d-array from txt file as an argument?

Tags: c

This is my C code and and  .txt file. I want to use 2d-array from .txt file as a function argument. However, when I run this code, program gives error at the call function lines such:

```
[Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[C]' to 'int (*)[3]' for argument '1' to 'int rec_ped(int (*)[3], int)'.
```

Other words, my function `rec_ped` cannot accept the 2d-array from .txt file.

Could you help me about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rec_ped(int k[18][3], int idx) {
  int sire, dam;

  sire = k[idx - 1][1];
  dam = k[idx - 1][2];

  printf("%d ", sire);

  if (sire != 0)
    rec_ped(k, sire);

  if (dam != 0)
    rec_ped(k, dam);
}

int main() {
  int R = 18;
  int C = 3;

  int A[R][C];
  FILE *fp;
  int i, j;
  fp = fopen("t.txt", "r");

  for (i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < C; j++) {
      fscanf(fp, "%d", &A[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < C; j++) {
      A[i][j];

      rec_ped(A, 18);  // <--- there is error!!!
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

my file is a.txt as below;

```
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
6 1 3
7 1 5
8 0 2
9 4 6
10 0 0
11 1 0
12 4 10
13 7 11
14 1 6
15 13 0
16 1 15
17 4 14
18 16 17
```

Comment: What compiler and version  are you using?

Comment: your function prototype specifies `int[18][3]`, but you are passing in arrays of varying lengths.

Comment: Quick fix: change `int A[R][C];` to `int A[18][3];`.

Comment: I'm using Dev C++,  5.11 version

Comment: Are you using Dev C++, 5.11 to compile this a C code or C++ code?

Comment: `A[i][j];` in the nested loop has no effect/doesn't do anything.

Comment: Other distraction `int rec_ped(int k[18][3], int idx)` does not return a value.  Its OK as it is not used, yet still a distraction.

Comment: This is C code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an array decays to a pointer, it only applies to the outermost array dimension.  It does *not* apply to inner dimensions.  So `int (*)[3]` and `int (*)[C]` are not the same, even though `C` happens to be 3 at the time the function is called.  A fixed size array and a variable length array can't be considered the same in this situation.

What you can do however is pass the dimensions of an array as parameters:

```
int rec_ped(int rows, int cols, int k[rows][cols], int idx) {
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
rec_ped(R, C, A, 18);
```

Comment: the const idea above is interesting but i would prefer this way if i were reading it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Make `C` a constant (`#define C 3`)!

Problem is: Without `C` being constant, but a variable, it *could* have been modified before declaring the array, so the latter actually is a VLA. The function, in contrast, expects a fixed size array, so types don't match.

Be aware you don't have to make `R` constant:

```
int rec_ped(int k[18][3], int idx);
```

is equivalent to

```
int rec_ped(int k[][3], int idx);
```

which is equivalent to

```
int rec_ped(int (*k)[3], int idx);
```

i. e. the function actually accepts a pointer to an array of length 3 just like `void f(int*);` accepts a pointer to int. In both cases, the pointer could reference the first element of an array (array of array or array of int respectively) or just a single element...

Comment: Making `C` a _constant_ would work like `#define C 3`.  Are you suggesting `const int C = 3;`?  The later does not work in C.

Comment: @chux Really??? GCC accepts fine, is this an extension? Before I start searching now myself, do you by accident have the appropriate reference to standard available?

Comment: It is as in [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53230899/2410359) answer.  `int (*)[3]` and `int (*)[C]` are not the same. With `const int C = 3; const int R = 18;  int A[R][C];`, `A` is still a VLA.  Try `const int C = 3` and `int rec_ped(int k[18][4], int idx)`.  Does gcc error on that in C?

Comment: The source of this disconnect may be that in C, a `const` is not as constant as `const` is in C++.

Comment: @chux Weird, gcc accepts all these combinations. Is this a bug?

Comment: I think this falls into UB that gcc does not detect.  Interesting that Dev C++, 5.11 does find it.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't understand what is the problem about this exactly....